# Is it possible to get hex value from input type: color and apply to form values that get outputted onto a table once submitted?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

it's my first time posting here so please advise on what more I should provide!

I made a little CRUD app in Angular. It's just a simple form with 4 fields, a color picker using input type='color' and a submit button. When you click submit the info gets stored and is displayed in a table next to the form.

I'm still new to JavaScript (TypeScript) and I would like some help with the color. Let's say once you fill out the form and before hitting submit you choose the color Aqua #00FFFF, how would I apply the color to the text after the user clicks submit? I'm able to extract the Hex Code, but can't figure out the rest!

This is the submit portion

```
onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
const data = Object.assign({}, form.value);
delete data.id;
if (form.value.id == null) {
  this.firestore.collection('catsanddogs').add(data);
} else {
  this.firestore.doc('catsanddogs/' + form.value.id).update(data);
}
form.resetForm(form);
this.toastr.success('You have successfully logged your Cat or Dog!', 'Logged');
console.log(form);
}
```

This is where I subscribe to the data

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getCatsandDogs().subscribe(actionArray => {
      this.list = actionArray.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data() } as CatsorDogs;
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the HTML for the table and the id is what's used to identify the document in Firebase!

```
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let catdog of list">    
  <td>{{ catdog .hmCode }} - {{ catdog .fullName }}</td>
  <td (click)="onEdit(catdog )">{{ catdog .position }}</td>
  <td (click)="onEdit(catdog )">{{ catdog .attitude }}</td>
  <td><a class="btn text-danger" (click)="onDelete(catdog .id)"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></td>
</tr>
```

I expect the outputted text to be whatever color the user selects.

Here's a screenshot of an identical app!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zg1wq4v28j3hw9i/Screenshot%20%281%29.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it with style binding in angular.
For example keep a class variable named selectedColor. Assign it on submit with the hex value selected by the user. You need to bind that variable to your html element's color like below.

```
<i [style.color]="selectedColor">Lorem ipsum...</i>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I was on the right track, but was instead trying stuff like [ngStyle] and [ngClass].